# Why does silverlight exist?

Tags: silverlight

Why not to empower WPF or ASP.NET instead of creating a new product?

Comment: The are good reasons why, there are correct answers available, its not subjective, I don't see any argumentative element to the question.  What's the deal here?

Comment: Ups!! By the way, my question was not intended to be argumentative. I only wanted to better understand how silverlight fits in the Web World. Sorry if I was missunderstood.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: The question doesn't make sense.  The three technologies are (almost) completely non-overlapping.

Comment: @SLaks:  It doesn't make sense to you because you know that they are non-overlapping, perhaps Eduardo doesn't know that, hence the question.  We have to cater for all levels of knowledge and experience here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET is simply a server-side language for websites.  While they have added support for things like AJAX ASP.NET Controls, it still can't come close to the level of richness Silverlight is capable of.

And then WPF requires the 200+ MB .NET Framework which can only run on Windows.

Silverlight was created as a lightweight 5 MB plugin that can run on Windows and Mac alike while meeting strict security guidelines for Internet use.  From my point of view, Silverlight is a different tool for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is meant for regular desktop applications and cannot be embedded in a webpage (XBAP isn't the same), and ASP.Net has nothing to do with Silverlight.  (ASP.Net is a server-side technology; Silverlight is client-side)

Answer (score 0):

To complete with flash and offer an all in one solution to all types of development and take over the world. Not that it will beat flash and its lineup of tools any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Because no matter how you empower ASP.NET or WPF you won't get the richness of Silverlight, Flash, ... in a web browser. Javascript's kind of limited.

Comment: maybe this was true in the past, but it's quickly becoming completely false. e.g. http://ajaxian.com/archives/gordon-flash-runtime-implemented-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET runs on the server, what was needed is something to run on the client.

WPF is empowered enough already, what was needed is something which can run on the client in a secure manner and that can't be used easily to do malicous things.  In other words far from "empowering" WPF, some form of WPF needed to be seriously curtailed.

In addition it can't be assumed that a full .NET framework is present on the client, Silverlight is designed to contain just enough of the needed framework to make things happen with minimal requirements on the client.

Answer (score 0):

A better question might be - why are WPF and Silverlight 2 separate things?

My best guess is that the decision was made to separate them "because we always have separate technologies for developing web vs. developing desktop applications" - but things are not nearly so cleanly split anymore and would make sense to see the 2 merge together.

Answer (score 0):

Probably starting from scratch you wouldn't have both Silverlight and WPF.

I suspect that deep in the MSFT psyche they still don't 'get' the web - WPF was a way of modernising drawing on the desktop, adapting it to web was obviously an afterthought.